# Limitation with angular orderby array?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a limitation with the number of values within an angular orderby predicate? I can't get anything with more than 2 fields to work.  Meaning anything past the 2nd index doesn't work.  If I shift the fields around and put the one that is 3rd to first it works.

Example:

```
['VendorName','ProductName','-ProductCost']
```

The value in the 3rd position or index 2 appears to be ignored unless i move it within the 1st or 2nd positions of the array.  I could be completely overlooking something, but I can't get it to work.  The first two fields work fine.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work correctly in this Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nHBQrJKXuGNkZ55VNPl8?p=preview

Click the *Sort Name, Phone, Age* button.

Comment: Phil, that example only has one value in the predicate.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?  It's doing name, then phone, then age.  ng-click="predicate=['name','phone','age']"